# I can't figure out what is wrong with my code

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, operating-system

I am trying to **scrape** data from html files about top 10 movies and here is the [link](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/). I want to **scrape** these info: titles, audience_scores and tomato_meter_score. but every time I run this code:

```
df_list = []
    for movie_html in os.listdir(folder):
        with open(os.path.join(folder, movie_html)) as file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'utf-8')
            title = soup.find('h1')
            audience_score = soup.find('div', class_="score-icon-audience left").find_all('span') 
   [1].contents[0][:-1]
            tomato_meter = soup.find('div', class_="score-icon-critic right").find_all('span') 
   [1].contents[0][:-1]
            df_list.append({'title' : title, 'audience_score' : audience_score, 'tomato_meter' : 
    tomato_meter})
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['title', 'audience_score', 'tomato_meter'])        `folder = 
    'rtmovies_html'  #this is the directory containing the 10 html files.
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
    FeatureNotFound                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-96935eee023c> in <module>
          2 for movie_html in os.listdir(folder):
          3     with open(os.path.join(folder, movie_html)) as file:
    ----> 4         soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'utf-8')
          5         title = soup.find('h1')
          6         audience_score = soup.find('div', class_="score-icon-audience left").find_all('span') 
    [1].contents[0][:-1]

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, 
    parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, element_classes, **kwargs)
        241             builder_class = builder_registry.lookup(*features)
        242             if builder_class is None:
    --> 243                 raise FeatureNotFound(
        244                     "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
        245                     "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"

    FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: utf-8. Do you need to 
    install a parser library?
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you re-title your post so that it's specifically about the question and not just a request for help?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap. To scrap means to throw things away like rubbish

Comment: Thanks a lot for your notion. I am sure typing the missing letter e in scrape is gonna fix my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a valid parser so that BeautifulSoup can work its magic.

Try "pip install -U lxml" and modify line 4 like this:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')`

Also, try modifying line 3 as follows:

`with open(os.path.join(folder, movie_html), encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')`

Comment: First thank you for noticing.                                                                                                     I took you advice and did the two step you recommended but unfortunately I got this error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 382974: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Michael Samuel: No pb. I edited my post in order to address this error message.

Comment: Thank you for your help.